# Exception sorting c#

Tags: c#

I'm getting below "index out of range" with below code when it reaches last line.
 Can anyone help on this to find out whats wrong

```
List<string> mailInfoList = new List<string>();
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {

        string strSubject = row["Subject"].ToString();
        string strEmailFrom =row["EmailFrom"].ToString();
        string strEmailTo =row["EmailTo"].ToString();
        string strEmailCC =row["EmailCc"].ToString();
        string strEmailContent=row["EmailContent"].ToString();
        string strCreatedOn =row["CreatedOn"].ToString();

        mailInfoList.Add(strSubject);
        mailInfoList.Add(strEmailFrom);
        mailInfoList.Add(strEmailTo);
        mailInfoList.Add(strEmailCC);
        mailInfoList.Add(strEmailContent);
        mailInfoList.Add(strCreatedOn);
        var newList = mailInfoList.OrderBy(x => x[1]).ThenBy(x => x[2]).ToList();

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? because it seems like you're trying to sort your list according to the 2nd then 3rd character but it seems like not every string in the list is at least 2 or 3 characters long.

Comment: ok..im doing wrong here..my goal is to read all the values in data table and sort based on Subject and createdon..I need to pass the sortedlist to do some processing..please help me..i dont have much idea on this.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here. Try thing instead:

```
var mailInfoList = new List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, DateTime>>();
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {

        string strSubject = row["Subject"].ToString();
        string strEmailFrom = row["EmailFrom"].ToString();
        string strEmailTo = row["EmailTo"].ToString();
        string strEmailCC = row["EmailCc"].ToString();
        string strEmailContent = row["EmailContent"].ToString();
        // Do proper error handling here
        DateTime strCreatedOn = DateTime.Parse(row["CreatedOn"].ToString());

        mailInfoList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, DateTime>(
            strSubject, strEmailFrom, strEmailTo, strEmailCC, strEmailContent, strCreatedOn
            ));

        var newList = mailInfoList.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item6).ToList();

    }
}
```

It'll sort your items by Subject then by Creation date. Just make sure that `DateTime.Parse` doesn't throw error (you can also use `DateTime.TryParse`

Comment: Thanks a lot..will try

Comment: Thanks a lot..that solved my sorting.I need one more thing to be done in sorting.
row 1 [subject] column in datatable  "ABC / Vess / 11371503 /C report "
row 2  [subject] column in dtatable "Value/BEY/11371503/A report"         I need to compare the values inside subject column based on / and if the value before / is same,i should look for next value before next slash and sort..Is there any recommendation to achieve this.Thanks.

Comment: Glad that helped. If it solved this particular problem then please [mark it as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/). As for your 2nd problem you want the spaces removed?

Comment: i want to split the values based on"/" and compare the values.My intention is to sort the row based on the values inside subject column......For eg..if value after 2nd slash is same for 2 rows,i need to check the values after 3rd slash and make A report to sort first.

Comment: @Priya You can split based on the `/` like this: `row["Subject"].ToString().Split(new[] {'/'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`. It'll return an array of strings that you can compare. If there are more details or requirements then feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot..I'll ask new question

Comment: ive added new ques to check if i can add to the existing sort list.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331339/array-comparision-and-sorting-to-list-c-sharp         thanks for ur help with my prev ques..

Comment: can u pls help with my new question posted above

Comment: @Priya hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that when you use `OrderBy(x => x[1])` **x** refer to each index of `mailInfoList` with type of `String`, And x[1] refere to second character of this index.

So are you sure every index of List has a length of 1 at minimum?

I suggest you to use:

```
var newList = mailInfoList.where( y => y.lenght > 0).OrderBy(x => x[1]).ThenBy(x => x[2]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create class model which similar to data tables object, from your example it's looks something like this,

```
public class Emails
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string EmailFrom { get; set; }
    public string EmailTo { get; set; }
    public string EmailCc { get; set; }
    public string EmailContent { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

and your update code block becomes,

```
List<Emails> mailInfoList = new List<Emails>();
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        Emails email = new Emails();
        email.Subject = row["Subject"].ToString();
        email.EmailFrom = row["EmailFrom"].ToString();
        email.EmailTo = row["EmailTo"].ToString();
        email.EmailCc = row["EmailCc"].ToString();
        email.EmailContent = row["EmailContent"].ToString();
        email.CreatedOn = Convert.ToDateTime(row["CreatedOn"].ToString());
        mailInfoList.Add(email);
    }
    var newList = mailInfoList.OrderBy(c => c.EmailFrom).ThenBy(n => n.CreatedOn);
}
```