# Array comparison and sorting to list c#

Tags: c#, sorting

I have data table with column "Subject", row 1 [subject] column in data table "ABC / Vesse / 11371503 /C report " row 2 [subject] column in data table "Value/BEY/11371503/A report" I need to compare the values inside subject column based on / and if the value before / is same,i should look for next value before next slash and sort..

As suggested, I'm splitting based on `/` strSubSplit. Can please help how to sort and add to the list after comparing. Thanks a lot.

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        string strSubject = row["Subject"].ToString();
        string strEmailFrom = row["EmailFrom"].ToString();
        string strEmailTo = row["EmailTo"].ToString();
        string strEmailCC = row["EmailCc"].ToString();
        string strEmailContent = row["EmailContent"].ToString();

        // Do proper error handling here
        DateTime strCreatedOn = DateTime.Parse(row["CreatedOn"].ToString());
        string[] strSubSplit= row["Subject"].ToString().Split(new[] {'/'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        mailInfoList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, DateTime>(strSubject, strEmailFrom, strEmailTo, strEmailCC, strEmailContent, strCreatedOn));

        var newList = mailInfoList.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item6).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clearly describe your requirement :)

Comment: Means "ABC / Vesse / 11371503 /C report" is one column value?

Comment: Did you mean "ABC / Vesse / 11371503 /C report" comes in sorted ordered like "11371503 / ABC/ C report/ Vesse"?

Comment: I want to sort the rows in datatable based on values inside [subject] column.strSubSplit would give arraylist to compare .sample data in [subject] column below.  "ABC / Vesse / 11371503 /C report " (row1)    "Value/BEY/11371503/A report" row 2..i need to compare the vlaues between "/' .with the above example if 2 rows have same value of 11371503 ,i will look for next string ' C Report" and 'A Report' and sort 'A Report' row first..I need to sort all rows in datatable and add to the new list to do other processing.

Comment: yes "ABC / Vesse / 11371503 /C report one column value\

Comment: @jatin..no ..first row had value of "ABC / Vesse / 11371503 /C report" and second row has value of "Value/BEY/11371503/A report" ..I need to spilt the values with "/"..if both rows have value of 11371503 ,i need to look for the next spilted string and make "A report" row first

Comment: sorry..didnt get you..u mean to say to add below lines aft  var newList = mailInfoList.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item6).ToList();string strSubject = string.Join("/",row["Subject"].ToString().Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList().OrderBy(x => x));

Comment: yeah true..was not giving the desired result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// assuming you'll already have the subjects of the emails
var subjects = new List<string>
{
    "ABC / Vesse / 11371503 /C report",
    "Value/BEY/11371503/A report"
};

var listOfItems = new List<Tuple<string, string, int, string>>();
subjects.ForEach(s =>
{
    var splits = s.Split(new[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();

    // Do proper error checking before the int.Parse and make sure every array has 4 elements
    listOfItems.Add(
        new Tuple<string, string, int, string>(splits[0], 
                                                splits[1], 
                                                int.Parse(splits[2]), 
                                                splits[3]));
});

var newList = listOfItems
    .OrderBy(x => x.Item3) // the number
    .ThenBy(x => x.Item4) // {x} report
    .ToList();
```

Comment: As per ur code,the sorted subject is added to newList .how can i add sortedlist to the existing list to get all the values.Thanks for all ur help.

Comment: mailInfoList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, DateTime>(
                               strSubject, strEmailFrom, strEmailTo, strEmailCC, strEmailContent, strCreatedOn));}

Answer (score 0):

First Row contains `ABC / Vesse / 11371503 /C report`
and Second contains `Value /BEY /11371503 /A report`

Try,

```
string strSubject = string.Join("/",row["Subject"]
                                   .ToString()
                                   .Split(new[] { '/' },
                                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
                               ).ToList().OrderBy(x => x));
```

now updated values are contains

Row 1 `11371503 /ABC /C report/Vesse`
Row 2 `11371503 /A report/BEY /Value`

and in your newList variables sorted again based on the subject,

```
 var newList = mailInfoList.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item6).ToList();
```

Which give your final result becomes

Row 1 `11371503 /A report/BEY /Value`
Row 2 `11371503 /ABC /C report/Vesse`